# How could my application press the OK button when an AlertDialog popup?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, wifip2p

I am developing an application using the `WifiP2pManager`. When one phone is trying to connect to another, they will form a wifi-p2p group and an `AlertDialog` would popup by the `WifiP2PService`. The `AlertDialog` is kind of annoying and in my program I have other better way for the users to authenticate the connection. I am wondering are there any way to get the `AlertDialog` in my code and press the `OK` button for the user? I mean, is it feasible, technically?

------------------A small update---------------------

To be clear, the AlertDialog is generated by a "SYSTEM SERVICE", not by my application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/) to wait for specific views to appear on the screen and click on them.

Comment: After a little research, I found that Robotium cannot work on the dialog popup by another application. Thank you for you advice but any other idea?